# Not able to make build in angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, build

```
[error] Error: Call retries were exceeded
at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (C:\Users\AkashGupta\source\repos\LMS\LMS\ClientApp\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\ChildProcessWorker.js:230:21)
at ChildProcessWorker._onExit (C:\Users\AkashGupta\source\repos\LMS\LMS\ClientApp\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\ChildProcessWorker.js:307:12)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
```

[image]

{
"name": "LMS",
"version": "0.0.0",
"license": "MIT",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build --extract-css",
"build:ssr": "npm run build -- --app=ssr --output-hashing=media",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^11.2.14",
"@angular/cdk": "^12.1.3",
"@angular/cli": "~11.2.14",
"@angular/common": "11.2.14",
"@angular/compiler": "11.2.14",
"@angular/core": "~11.2.14",
"@angular/forms": "~11.2.14",
"@angular/material": "^11.2.13",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.14",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.14",
"@angular/router": "~11.2.14",
"@azure/msal-angular": "^2.0.2",
"@azure/msal-browser": "^2.16.1",
"@azure/storage-blob": "^12.6.0",
"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.9.0",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
"@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
"@fullcalendar/core": "4.4.0",
"@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client": "^3.0.0",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^10.0.0",
"@types/jasmine": "3.3.16",
"@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.8",
"@types/jquery": "^3.5.6",
"angularx-social-login": "^3.5.5",
"bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
"chart.js": "^2.9.4",
"chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^1.0.0",
"file-saver": "^2.0.5",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"install": "^0.13.0",
"jquery": "^3.6.0",
"jspdf": "^2.3.1",
"ng-file-upload": "^12.2.13",
"ng2-charts": "^2.4.3",
"ngx-toastr": "^14.0.0",
"primeflex": "2.0.0",
"primeicons": "4.1.0",
"primeng": "^11.3.0",
"quill": "1.3.7",
"rxjs": "~6.6.0",
"tslib": "^2.0.0",
"xlsx": "^0.17.0",
"zone.js": "0.10.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.6",
"@angular/cli": "~11.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.0",
"@angular/language-service": "~10.0.1",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/jspdf": "^2.0.0",
"@types/node": "^6.0.118",
"codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
"jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
"karma": "~5.1.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
"karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
"protractor": "~7.0.0",
"ts-node": "~8.3.0",
"tslint": "~6.1.0",
"typescript": "~4.0.2",
"webpack": "^4.39.2"
}
}

---

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that this issue got fixed on v13.1.0. Try to upgrade/degrade on node v13.1.0 & check if this works for you.